# Windows 10 install freeze

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

During the installation of W10 the setup freezes at 64% installing features and drivers, configuring settings 0%. I've used the installation from w10 update app that was on my w8.1. I have dell inspiron 7536 with i7, 8gb ram and 256gb ssd. 
I've also tried to restart the process, but the freeze is in the same point. I was waiting for 1 hour and nothing moved. 
Any ideas how to solve this other than downloading w10 iso and booting it from usb?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to try a different method, a freeze like that and assuming it occured during a driver install, it may just happen the same way again. If you have any removable devices of any type, removing them and keeping the system more bare bones could help, that can even include extra input devices you use to push buttons during install. Then plug them in one by one  slowly getting any update/drivers for them , and rebooting even to insure the sucessfull operation of each item.

Comment: @Psycogeek thank you for the answer. I've removed all the devices and peripherals and restarted the process but sadly the problem remains the same.

Comment: Its always better to upgrade offline rather than from inside windows. You could [try a clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) before launching the installer.

Comment: [Your model is not on the tested list at Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN297954?dgc=SM&cid=266887&lid=5563896#Inspiron-NB) Just means they have not tested it and do not provide drivers for W10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be dell inspiron 7000 specific. Solution is to update the bios drivers. For other issues with w10 upgrade check [enter link description here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f5ivm/why_cant_you_upgrade_to_windows_10_list_your/)